# How do I insert an if statement into a template string literal in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to insert an if statement into a template string literal( I think that's what it's called). Please let me know if I am called this wrong because I am not too sure. I'm not an experienced coder. Just self taught with some YouTube videos. Anyways, at the very bottom of the code you will find an if statement. That if statement needs to go into the template block of code in the variable $element. I have indicated the exact line. It's about 4 lines up from the last quotation. The code itself is working find. I just need the right syntax to add in the if statement so I don't get errors. Context: this function is used to generate multiple product cards for a product based on every product entry in the mysql database. I am trying to display an "in cart" symbol for every product that is "in the cart". Everything is working fine it's just that the if statement is not in the right position. It needs to go inside the product card.

`My Code`:

```
function component($productname,$genre,$beat_tags,$productprice1,$productprice2,$productprice3,$productprice4,$productimg,$product_id) {
        $element = "
            <div class=\"track_column\">
                <!--<form action=\"tracks.php\" method=\"post\">-->
                    <div class=\"track_card_content\">
                        <div class=\"track_image\">
                            <img width=\"50\" height=\"50\" src=\"$productimg\" alt=\"product image\">
                            <div class=\"mediPlayer\">
                                <audio class=\"listen\" preload=\"none\" data-size=\"50\" src=\"Multiple-circular-player-master/sounds/piano.mp3\"></audio>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=\"card-body\">
                                    <h5 class=\"card-title\">$productname</h5>
                                    <p class=\"card-genre\">
                                        Genre: $genre
                                    </p>
                                    <p class=\"card-text\">
                                        Tags: $beat_tags
                                    </p>
                                        <span class=\"price\">$$productprice1+</span>
                                    <div class=\"cart-track-button\">Add to Cart</div>
                                        <div class=\"license_dropdown\" style>
                                            <div class=\"license_dropdown_options\">
                                                <ul class=\"license_dropdown_options_main\">
                                                    <li>
                                                    <form action=\"tracks.php\" method=\"post\">
                                                        <button class=\"option_button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"add\">
                                                            <div class=\"option_title\">Basic</div>
                                                            <div class=\"option_price\">$$productprice1</div>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$product_id'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_price' value='$productprice1'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='category' value='lease'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='option' value='basic'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                    <form action=\"tracks.php\" method=\"post\">
                                                        <button class=\"option_button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"add\">
                                                            <div class=\"option_title\">Premium</div>
                                                            <div class=\"option_price\">$$productprice2</div>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$product_id'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_price' value='$productprice2'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='category' value='lease'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='option' value='premium'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                    <form action=\"tracks.php\" method=\"post\">
                                                        <button class=\"option_button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"add\">
                                                            <div class=\"option_title\">Unlimited</div>
                                                            <div class=\"option_price\">$$productprice3</div>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$product_id'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_price' value='$productprice3'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='category' value='lease'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='option' value='unlimited'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <button class=\"option_button\" onclick=\"togglePopup()\">
                                                            <div class=\"option_title\">Exclusive</div>
                                                            <div class=\"option_price\">$productprice4</div>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='category' value='exclusive'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='option' value='exclusive'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
                                                            <!--for merchandise put 'merchandise????'-->
                                                        </button>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <!--<div class=\"item_added_to_cart\">
                                        <img src=\"images/website/shopping_cart_added.png\"> Need to put it right here!!!!!
                                    </div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!--</form>-->
            </div>
        ";
    echo $element;
    //Need to move this into the template literal string...
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['cart']); $i++) { 
            if ($_SESSION['cart'][$i]['product_id'] == $product_id) {
                echo '<div class="item_added_to_cart"><img src="images/website/shopping_cart_added.png"></div>';
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //do nothing...
        echo '';
    }   
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: The simplest solution is to just create another variable before `$element` that is null by default but has your HTML in it if your conditions are true. You can then just use your variable just like the other ones.

Comment: Also, although nothing is inherently wrong with the code as you wrote it, I personally find that when I have more than a simple amount of HTML in my PHP (one or two tags, maybe), I'm usually doing something that will be harder and harder to maintain in the future. In your specific case, your function appears to be very specific to one thing to the point that I don't think it will be too reusable. Could this code be moved to the call-site itself, and remove the need for the function? Once again, nothing wrong, just my own opinion/observation.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I hear what you are saying. This function is actually in a separate functions file, and I use it in my actual product page to make my life easier and automatically load all products from the database.

Comment: @ChrisHaas You the man. Your solution worked fine :')... Thank you so much. I've been struggling.

Comment: If anybody has this problem I took the if statement and put it first within the function and then within the if statement created a separate variable ($elementInCart) that contain the html string(my in cart img) if the conditions were met and set if null for the else part of the if statement. Just like @ChrisHaas just said. Thank you once again ChrisHaas. You the man!

Comment: @johnnyjohn400, could you write that as an answer and just accept it?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Ok my bad. I am still getting used to this platform.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody has this problem I took the if statement and put it first within the function and then within the if statement created a separate variable($elementInCart) that contain the html string( aka my in cart img) if the conditions were met and set it null for the else part of the if statement. Just like @ChrisHaas just said. Thank you once again ChrisHaas. You the man!

Full coded answer down below:

`Answer`:

```
function component($productname,$genre,$beat_tags,$productprice1,$productprice2,$productprice3,$productprice4,$productimg,$product_id) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['cart']); $i++) { 
                if ($_SESSION['cart'][$i]['product_id'] == $product_id) {
                    $elementInCart = '<img src="images/website/shopping_cart_added.png">';
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $elementInCart = null;
        }
        $element = "
            <div class=\"track_column\">
                <!--<form action=\"tracks.php\" method=\"post\">-->
                    <div class=\"track_card_content\">
                        <div class=\"track_image\">
                            <img width=\"50\" height=\"50\" src=\"$productimg\" alt=\"product image\">
                            <div class=\"mediPlayer\">
                                <audio class=\"listen\" preload=\"none\" data-size=\"50\" src=\"Multiple-circular-player-master/sounds/piano.mp3\"></audio>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=\"card-body\">
                                    <h5 class=\"card-title\">$productname</h5>
                                    <p class=\"card-genre\">
                                        Genre: $genre
                                    </p>
                                    <p class=\"card-text\">
                                        Tags: $beat_tags
                                    </p>
                                        <span class=\"price\">$$productprice1+</span>
                                    <div class=\"cart-track-button\">Add to Cart</div>
                                        <div class=\"license_dropdown\" style>
                                            <div class=\"license_dropdown_options\">
                                                <ul class=\"license_dropdown_options_main\">
                                                    <li>
                                                    <form action=\"tracks.php\" method=\"post\">
                                                        <button class=\"option_button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"add\">
                                                            <div class=\"option_title\">Basic</div>
                                                            <div class=\"option_price\">$$productprice1</div>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$product_id'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_price' value='$productprice1'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='category' value='lease'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='option' value='basic'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                    <form action=\"tracks.php\" method=\"post\">
                                                        <button class=\"option_button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"add\">
                                                            <div class=\"option_title\">Premium</div>
                                                            <div class=\"option_price\">$$productprice2</div>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$product_id'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_price' value='$productprice2'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='category' value='lease'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='option' value='premium'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                    <form action=\"tracks.php\" method=\"post\">
                                                        <button class=\"option_button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"add\">
                                                            <div class=\"option_title\">Unlimited</div>
                                                            <div class=\"option_price\">$$productprice3</div>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$product_id'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='product_price' value='$productprice3'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='category' value='lease'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='option' value='unlimited'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <button class=\"option_button\" onclick=\"togglePopup()\">
                                                            <div class=\"option_title\">Exclusive</div>
                                                            <div class=\"option_price\">$productprice4</div>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='category' value='exclusive'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='option' value='exclusive'>
                                                            <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class=\"item_added_to_cart\">
                                        $elementInCart
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!--</form>-->
            </div>
        ";
    echo $element;
    }
```

Further context:
This is a function in a separate php file. This function is used within my actual products page to output all products from my database by using the coded format as show in the template string literal(I think that's the formal name but don't quote me). This function makes my life easier by simply outputting all my products on to my products page as I input them into the database. My problem was that I wanted to indicate that the item was already in the cart using an image that I create to signify "in cart" status. However, you can't just put an if statement straight into a string as far as I know. Anyways, with Chris Haas's help, I was able to take what I had so far and make it work. So now I have a custom product page that shows whether or not the product is in the customer's cart.